# GeoServer polygon intersecting features of WFS

Tags: openlayers, wfs

How to get all the features intersecting a polygon using wfs.I am able to get all the features from WFS geoserver but dont know how to pass a polygon to get only specific features which are intersecting with the polygon.Please provide few lines of code in ol3

Comment: Please show what you already have. What have you already looked at? Have you looked at the OpenLayers 3 samples (e.g. http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/vector-wfs.js)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending the way you execute the request on your server. If you use GET request then you may use the following

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typeName=topp:states&outputFormat=GML2&FILTER=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><Intersects><PropertyName>GEOM_COLUMN</PropertyName><gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList> 
            PLACE THE POLYGON COORDS HERE
</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></Intersects></Filter>`

this will make a request to your geoserver requesting features form layer `topp:states` whose geometry column name is `GEOM_COLUMN` and have an `any_interact` relationship with the supplied polygon

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response After updating code I get error please see in my Question I added there

Comment: can you provide the GET url you use? The one I see in the question is defenanlty not the right one.

Comment: Yes It was my mistake thanks its working perfectly. I deleted  extra comments from my question so that any other will not get confused

Comment: no probs. glad to help!